# Add GitLab Web hook for all projects in group

Tags: gitlab, webhooks

I would like all my projects in a GitLab group to have shared configuration for a webhook:

```
<MY_JENKINS_INSTANCE>/git/notifyCommit?url=$CHANGED_REPOSITORY
```

[GitLab webhook documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/web_hooks/web_hooks.html) suggests it should be possible:

> If you have a big set of projects in the one group then it will be convenient for you to configure web hooks globally for the whole group. You can add the group level web hooks on the group settings page.

That sound exactly like what I am after though I see no such thing on group settings page in my gitlab 7.0.0. I was not able to find out if this feature is not newer than that in the [changelog](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/CHANGELOG).

Does the feature exist? How do I use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's possible in the enterprise version only:

> In *GitLab Enterprise Edition* you can configure web hooks globally for the whole group. You can add the group level web hooks on the group settings page Settings > Web Hooks.

Comment: Although this is correct, [you can manage webhooks via the API in CE](https://gitlab.com/help/api/projects.md#hooks).

Comment: @VertigoRay that page seems to be describing project hooks only, and the hook-related endpoints require `:id` ("The ID or URL-encoded path of the project"). I tried a group id, but it doesn't seem to work (at least in GitLab Community Edition 8.14.4).

Comment: @seanf You're correct. What I was suggesting, albeit not very clear, is that you can query each project in a group, and set the webhooks for each project using a seperate Jenkins Job (or even GitLab CI) and a little scripting.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on [@VertigoRay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048819/add-gitlab-web-hook-for-all-projects-in-group#comment74057393_36083099)'s comments, here's a procedure to do it using GitLab CE API:

Have, or create an user in GitLab and a personal access token with `api` scope:

- User (top right avatar) > Settings (menu) > Access tokens (sidebar)
- Check `api` scope (checkbox)
- Click on create personal access token (button)
- **<my_personal_token>** is the value in *Your New Personal Access Token* (text field)

Perform an HTTP request to get all projects:

```
GET https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects
Private-Token: <my_personal_token>
Accept: application/json
```

For each project in the response:

- *id* which is the **<project_ID>** to be used in the next request URL
- Convert the value of *ssh_url_to_repo* so that it becomes URL encoded **<encoded_ssh_url>**

  - Example: `ssh://git@example.com:1234/group/alpha.git` becomes `ssh%3A%2F%2Fgit%40example.com%3A1234%2Fgroup%2Falpha.git`

For each project, perform an HTTP request to create a hook:

```
POST https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_ID>/hooks
Private-Token: <my_personal_token>
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "url": "https://jenkins.example.com/git/notifyCommit?url=<encoded_ssh_url>",
  "enable_ssl_verification": true
}
```

This should be scripted in the langage of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Not suitable as a persistent solution, but this might be useful for someone looking for a one-time change (from the [raketasks documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/web_hooks.html)):

```
Add a webhook for projects in a given NAMESPACE
# omnibus-gitlab
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:web_hook:add URL="http://example.com/hook" NAMESPACE=acme
# source installations
bundle exec rake gitlab:web_hook:add URL="http://example.com/hook" NAMESPACE=acme RAILS_ENV=production
```